# How to Launch famo.us application into iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, famo.us

I have small Application in Famo.us framework. it is having some HTML form and .js files and it runs only in browser, but i want to run it as a appliction in iPhone and android phone.

so how to publish Famo.us Application into  android and apple store ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use Adobe **[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)** (*aka Apache Cordova*) to scaffold an iOS/Android project. phonegap works by wrapping your site in a native WebView, allowing developers to create mobile apps that can be released to the store using their existing web development skillset.

You will need the corresponding native development tools/SDKs in order to build your projects & submit them to the app store. Follow the getting started instructions, and once your project is created, place the contents of your web project into the 'www' folder.

There will be some platform specific nuances you need to consider, and make sure you don't start doing anything until the 'onDeviceReady' event is fired by Cordova, which signals the WebView is set up correctly and ready to go.